# Joomla custom module add javascript

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0

I am writing a custom module and I need to add javascript to my site.
This individual page only makes a query from the database (the template makes nothing with it)

I tried with this:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

// defining the base path.
if (stristr( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'win32' )) {
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'\..\..' ));
    } else define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' ));
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

    // including the main joomla files
     require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
     require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

    // Creating an app instance 
    $app =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

    $app->initialise();
    jimport( 'joomla.user.user' );
    jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );


    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$document = &JFactory::getDocument();   
$document->addScript('modules/mod_csk/js/num.js');
```

But no javascript was added to my site.

Furthermore I tried I simple js code but it doesn't render:

```
echo "<td>"?><script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello");<? echo "</td>"
```

I don't know the reason, maybe something I missed.
This simple page is independent from joomla system at this moment (so it makes nothing to switch off and on there the settings)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try the following: $document->addScript('text/javascript','/modules/mod_csk/js/num.js');

Comment: Also, just because I'm curious, why would you include the Joomla core includes files, if you are loading the script as a module you already have access to the api without the need to redeclare these files. If the module isn't going to actually "do" anything you may want to look at a system plug in instead of a module.